# Routing problem in laravel 7 in view a folder name dashboard in dashboard folder a new folder admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

[image]

My question is routing problem **website.com/dashboard/admin/** but this route not working please
help me

in view a folder a dashboard folder and in dashboard folder a new folder admin

web route page code

```
     Route::group(['middleware'=>['loginAuth']],function(){
     Route:: resource('/dashboard','DashboardController');
     Route:: resource('/dashboard/admin','AdminController');

  });
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Can you please share your `AdminController` ?

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $user = admin::all();
        return view('admin.index',compact('user')); 
    }

Comment: in controller  return a  view ` public function index()
    {
        $user = admin::all();
        return view('admin.index',compact('user')); 
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently requesting a view that doesn't exist:

```
view('admin.index') // Looking for /views/admin/index.blade.php
```

According to your file structure, you need to call the following view:

```
view('dashboard.admin.index') // Looking for /views/dashboard/admin/index.blade.php
```

As the documentation says: (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#creating-views)

> Views may also be nested within subdirectories of the resources/views directory.
>   "Dot" notation may be used to reference nested views. For example, if your view 
>   is stored at resources/views/admin/profile.blade.php, you may reference it like
>   so:
>
> ```
> return view('admin.profile', $data);
> ```

This `Dot` notation is very common in Laravel to access subfolders elements - you will see it as well in the blade components such as `@extend` or `@include`

Comment: if i have a template file in dashboard folder how to @extends in  dashboard admin index.blade.php

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the question. What do you mean by `template` file? And what do you need to exclude?

Comment: `@extends`  any file

Comment: if you need to use `@extend()` or `@include()` , you can use the same `Dot` notation as for the view. For example you may want to extend your dashboard layout, you will use: `@extend('dashboard.admin.layout')`

Comment: @Gnziet There's also documentation on [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade) and [Template Inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#template-inheritance)